# распознавание четырехугольников в OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Работаю над распознаванием фигур в *OpenCV*. Чтобы найти четырехугольник, смотрю на количество вершин:

```
while(contours)
{
    result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage,
    CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0);

    if(result->total==3 )
    {   
        CvPoint *pt[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
        }
        cvLine(src, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,0,250),4);
        cvLine(src, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,0,250),4);
        cvLine(src, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,0,250),4);
        cvLine(src, *pt[3], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,0,250),4);
    }
    contours = contours->h_next; 
}
```

Хорошо работает на рисунках, но на реальных фотографиях работает гораздо хуже (использую свертку, но тогда рисунки распознаются хуже). Какие еще способы можно использовать для распознавания четырехугольников? Как можно переделать преобразование Хафа для поиска прямоугольников?

Answer (score 1):

1. Осторожнее с `approxPolyDP` - понимаете наверно, что с ее помощью любой контур (сложнее треугольника) можно свести к четырехугольнику, если параметры подобрать... Лучше здесь ее вообще не использовать, а задать простую аппроксимацию при поиске контуров - `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`
2. Есть простой способ определить прямоугольник:

   - найти `RotatedRect` с помощью `minAreaRect`
   - вычислить площадь `RotatedRect` и сравнить с площадью контура - если модуль разницы площадей меньше некоторой погрешности, которая Вас бы устроила - это прямоугольник
3. Обратите внимание, что перспективное преобразование с легкостью делает из прямоугольников (в миру) трапеции или вообще четырехугольники (в кадре). 
   То, что я предложил, тоже не найдёт трапецию (в миру - прямоугольник, искаженный большим углом при перспективном преобразовании). Сначала нужно устранить последствия перспективного преобразования.
4. Алгоритмы поиска маркеров ARUCO в OpenCV справляются с перспективным преобразованием, если такая задача тоже стоит - я бы посоветовал изучить исходный код, как там это делается.
5. Также может быть полезна функция `HoughLines`